# Read comma-separated values in HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple HTML input element:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="value">
```

This field could have comma-separated values e.g. `ABC, DEF, GHI`. The field value when submitted must be exactly the same as when entered. However, when I am printing the field value to the console, I am getting

`ABC%2C+DEF%2C+GHI`.

I want `ABC, DEF, GHI`

I tried things like `decodeURIComponent` and `accept-charset="ISO-8859-1"` for the form, but they don't work. How can I prevent the encoding of the commas and spaces? Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you send data, it will be encoded.. you need to use decodedURIComponent when you receive the data, and then split it.

Comment: decodeURIComponent decodes the commas properly, but leaves the + sign for the spaces as they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before submiting, encode the value and it should work, according to my test

```
<form id="myForm" action="form.php" method="GET">
    <input id="encodeMe" name="string" value="this will be encoded correctly" />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>

$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    var enc = escape($("#encodeMe").val());
    $("#encodeMe").val(enc);
});
```

Comment: This is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. In JavaScript, the input field has to be handled thus:

```
decodeURIComponent(str.replace(/\+/g,' '))
```

where str = `ABC%2C+DEF%2C+GHI`. Only `decodeURIComponent` is not enough. Hope it helps!